# Covert Biopac/Acqknowledge file (.acq) to text file using R

Tags: r

I am currently converting +200 AcqKnowledge files to text files and as it takes a while I was wondering if it is possible to do this using R.

I found a place where they wrote that they had used:

install.packages("Biopacndf")

However I get this error message (and I have tried different versions of R): "package ‘Biopacndf’ is not available for this version of R".

1. Is there a place where I can find information about which version support that package?
2. Do any of you have an alternative idea on how to make an R script that can convert .acq files to .txt?

Hope you can help!